# Returning acquisition time of Landsat 7 image using Google Earth Engine JavaScript API

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, landsat, date

I try to get the timestamp of the least cloudy image for my region of interest (roi). I want to obtain the date of this image in the time range 2012-10-01 - 2012-12-31. I know that the image exists since I can get a real colour map but I get the following error when using the code below:

"Date: Parameter 'value' is required."

```js
var l7coll_2012 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LE07/C01/T1_SR')
.filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUD_COVER',25))
.select(['B7','B6' ,'B5' , 'B4' , 'B3', 'B2', 'B1'])
.filterDate('2012-10-01', '2012-12-30')
.map(function(image){
  var filled1a = image.focal_mean(2, 'square', 'pixels', 1)
  return filled1a.blend(image);
})

var l7_roi_2012 = l7coll_2012.median().clip(roi)
Map.addLayer(l7_roi_2012, {bands: ['B3', 'B2', 'B1'],min:0, max: 3000}, 'Real colour');

print('Timestamp: ', ee.Date(l7coll_2012.get('system:time_start')))
```

If I use the following adjustment, it works for landsat 8 images but I still get the same error for landsat 7 image.

```js
var date_2012 = l7coll_2012.reduceColumns(ee.Reducer.minMax(), ["system:time_start"])
print('Date 2012:' , ee.Date(date_2012.get('max')))
```

Working landsat 8 code:

```
var l8coll_2013 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR')
.filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUD_COVER',25))
.filterBounds(roi)
.filterDate('2013-10-01', '2013-12-30')
.map(function(image){
  return image.rename(['B0', 'B1', 'B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B5', 'B6', 'B7', 'B8', 'B9', 'B10', 'B11']);
})

var date_2013 = l8coll_2013.reduceColumns(ee.Reducer.minMax(), ["system:time_start"])
print('Date 2013:' , ee.Date(date_2013.get('max')))
```

Does anyone know how I can get the timestamp for a landsat 7 image?

Answer (score 1):

The function to fill the missing pixels changed the characteristics of the image in such a way that only the band reflectance was left, so there was no date to print. If I remove this part of the code:

```js
.map(function(image){
  var filled1a = image.focal_mean(2, 'square', 'pixels', 1)
  return filled1a.blend(image);
```

I do get the right timestamp using this code:

```js
var date_2012 = l7coll_2012.reduceColumns(ee.Reducer.minMax(), ["system:time_start"])
print('Date 2012:' , ee.Date(date_2012.get('max')))
```